# How to prevent Windows Forms designer from generating default value assignments for properties?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a user control with a property that is of a reference type.  The Windows Forms designer keeps generating code that assigns the property's initial value to null.  How can I prevent this?

I tried adding Reset and ShouldSerialize methods -- Reset had an empty body and ShouldSerialize always returned false -- but that did not work.  I also applied the BrowsableAttribute and set it to false.

Edit:

The property's type is a class in the same project.  It's not a component or control, just a plain class inheriting from Object.  Also, the property's setter calls a method using the property's value as its argument and the method does not accept null as a valid argument.

Example:

```
public MyClass Property1 
{
   get { return _property1; }
   set
   {
        _property1 = value;
        SomeMethod(value); // This method throws ArgumentNullException;
   }
}
```

Note: I do realize that get and set methods would probably be more appropriate here.

Comment: Please add an example. Just any ref type or a ref to a component/control?

Comment: Even if you don't manually set the default to NULL, the default will still be NULL implicitly for a ref type. What would you expect it to be?

Comment: I'm assuming that Windows Forms Designer is overwriting the value that you initially write to the control?

Comment: The setter on the property does more than just set the value of a field.  It also passes the value to a method that does not accept null values.  So really I should probably use get and set methods instead of a property for this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Murky, I could use a snippet.  Tell the designer that it shouldn't ever serialize the value of the property:

```
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public Image Aardvark { get; set; }
```

Comment: @Hans can we also supply a default value for a property and render it on designer ?