# Setting property of class type with TypeConverter from Property Panel produces expanded XAML, not string

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, typeconverter

I'm trying to create a User Control with a property whose type is a class I've defined. I'm using a `TypeConverter` to allow the property to be processed as a string. The application correctly handles reading XAML where the property is a string, but if the property is set to a string through the property panel, then the XAML contains an expanded syntax breaking out the user-defined class.

Concretely, since that was a bit hard to follow, I'm following [this Microsoft tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546926%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). I have the following code as a result:

**Complex.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ComplexTypeConverter))]
    public class Complex
    {
        private double m_real;
        private double m_imag;

        public Complex() { }
        public Complex(double r, double i)
        {
            m_real = r;
            m_imag = i;
        }

        public double Real
        {
            get { return m_real; }
            set { m_real = value; }
        }

        public double Imaginary
        {
            get { return m_imag; }
            set { m_imag = value; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0},{1}", this.m_real, this.m_imag);
        }

        public static Complex Parse(string complexNumber)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(complexNumber))
            {
                return new Complex();
            }

            // The parts array holds the real and 
            // imaginary parts of the object.
            string[] parts = complexNumber.Split(',');
            return new Complex(double.Parse(parts[0].Trim()), double.Parse(parts[1].Trim()));
        }
    }

    public class ComplexTypeConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        private static List<Complex> defaultValues = new List<Complex>();

        static ComplexTypeConverter()
        {
            defaultValues.Add(new Complex(0, 0));
            defaultValues.Add(new Complex(1, 1));
            defaultValues.Add(new Complex(-1, 1));
            defaultValues.Add(new Complex(-1, -1));
            defaultValues.Add(new Complex(1, -1));
        }

        // Override CanConvertFrom to return true for String-to-Complex conversions.
        public override bool CanConvertFrom(
            ITypeDescriptorContext context,
            Type sourceType)
        {
            if (sourceType == typeof(string))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
        }

        // Override CanConvertTo to return true for Complex-to-String conversions.
        public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(string))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
        }

        // Override ConvertFrom to convert from a string to an instance of Complex.
        public override object ConvertFrom(
            ITypeDescriptorContext context,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture,
            object value)
        {
            string text = value as string;

            if (text != null)
                            return Complex.Parse(text);                 

            return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
        }

        // Override ConvertTo to convert from an instance of Complex to string.
        public override object ConvertTo(
            ITypeDescriptorContext context,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture,
            object value,
            Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("destinationType");
            }

            //Convert Complex to a string in a standard format.
            Complex c = value as Complex;

            if (c != null && this.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType))
            {
                return c.ToString();
            }

            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }

        public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(
            ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            StandardValuesCollection svc = new StandardValuesCollection(defaultValues);
            return svc;
        }
    }
}
```

**ComplexNumberControl.xaml.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class ComplexNumberControl : UserControl
    {
        public ComplexNumberControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Complex ComplexNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return (Complex)this.GetValue(ComplexNumberProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                this.SetValue(ComplexNumberProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ComplexNumberProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "ComplexNumber",
          typeof(Complex),
          typeof(ComplexNumberControl),
          new PropertyMetadata(new Complex()));
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Grid>
        <my:ComplexNumberControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="88,78,0,0" x:Name="complexNumberControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I can add `ComplexNumber="0,0"` to the `ComplexNumberControl` with no error (and I know, from more complicated assemblies, that the property is correctly handled as the Complex number 0 + 0i). However, if I edit `ComplexNumber` in the property panel, the XAML changes to:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Grid>
        <my:ComplexNumberControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="88,78,0,0" x:Name="complexNumberControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <my:ComplexNumberControl.ComplexNumber>
                <my:Complex Imaginary="-1" Real="1" />
            </my:ComplexNumberControl.ComplexNumber>
        </my:ComplexNumberControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How can I ensure the generated XAML simply reads `ComplexNumber="1,-1"`, instead of the verbose `ComplexNumberControl.ComplexNumber` construct?

Comment: Perhaps this doesn't work because the complex type and converter are defined in the same assembly in which you are trying to use it? Try putting the ComplexNumber and its TypeConverter into a separate assembly and possibly the control too. Then create a WPF application that references that project or assembly and create an instance of the control in that.

Comment: Nope. I moved Complex.cs and `ComplexNumberControl` into a new Class library project (in the same solution); I still get the expanded XAML, just on a namespace that references the new class library assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost there and needs only two minor adjustments on **Complex** class to make it work as you expect:

1) Remove default public constructor:

```cs
public Complex() { } // <- delete this line
```

2) Add magical **DesignerSerializationVisibility** attribute to **Real** and **Imaginary** properties (or in general - to all properties with public setter):

```cs
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public double Real
{
    get { return m_real; }
    set { m_real = value; }
}

[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public double Imaginary
{
    get { return m_imag; }
    set { m_imag = value; }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd almost figured this was just a bug and wouldn't ever get an answer...

Comment: You are welcome, @Chowlett. In fact, for some reason this DesignerSerializationVisibility attribute is *not* mentioned in many articles related to the subject in context of WPF/XAML, but, on the other hand, was extensively used even at the time of WinForms for the pretty same thing.

Comment: For example - [How to prevent Windows Forms designer from generating default value assignments for properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961534/how-to-prevent-windows-forms-designer-from-generating-default-value-assignments)